# Forced out of memory java.. inconsistent java behavior

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I knowingly created the following class to cause out of memory error

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(true)
        {
            Test1 a = new Test1();
            sb.append(a.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

As I expected this above class fails with what I wanted...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
        at Test1.main(Test1.java:10)
```

but this:

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(true)
        {
            Test1 a = new Test1();
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            sb.append(a.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Does not crash. Runs just fine, by printing the object address over and over again on console.

My question is:

What difference a simple SOP made?

Comment: SOP is just delaying the crash.

Comment: @Ishtar actually it does not. Well at somepoint it might, but I monitored it for a good amount of time, and it does not crash.

Comment: @Ayusman: How much memory does your JVM have? Have you also observed memory consumption, for instance with `jconsole` ?

Comment: @Lukas I ran the class file from command prompt, w/o any -Xms/-Xmx parameters, so I guess should have started with default JVM allocation (32Mb if I am not wrong). In the windows XP task manager it shows the memory usage of the process to be 136K. In jconsole it says used memory=12,310 kbytes

Comment: @Ayusman: Check out my updated answer. So if you're really really patient, you can run your code for 15 days and wait for the inevitable to happen :-) Also, try to redirect output to `/dev/null`, as suggested by Ishtar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your assumption that there is no `OutOfMemoryError` is likely to be incorrect. It is just massively delayed. Printing a string that is getting bigger and bigger on the out stream takes so much time, that your loop may take an hour to run out of memory.

You can double-check this, by printing only every 10th, 100th, 1000th time. You'll see the error will occur the earlier the less IO you generate. Probably you'll see a curve like this in `jconsole`:

[image]

As you can see, the heap is slowly but steadily going up. Even if I try to force garbage collection (15:02 and 15:07), I cannot free all memory anymore. But since I'm still only at 5% of my heap, I'll stop running your code now :-)

Comment: and Ishtar thank you very much for the answers. As Lukas pointed out yes, my memory usage is increasing and looks like it will take really long before my code crashes. but it eventually will. Thanks guys. Lukas your suggestion to use jconsole really helped. Sometimes, I tend to forget the nice tools at my disposal. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Just tested a bit, the actual bottleneck is `sb.toString()`. This of course takes time proportional to the length of the string(buffer), so every next loop takes a tiny bit longer to execute. Before you run out of memory, after a few thousands loops, one loop will take a couple of seconds just to create the string.

Replacing `sb.toString()` by a `long` counter, makes it crash 'instantly' aswell. Removing the `System.out.println()` has little effect on speed.

On my computer `java -Xmx2m Test1 > /dev/null` takes about **8 minutes** to crash. With a normal heap size this could take days. (Feel free to try it.)

Comment: +1 for redirecting to `/dev/null`. I crashed my Eclipse when trying to run this code :-)